# variable is not setting inside mysql sp

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to set @in_client_id inside MySQL sp , but it is always 0 . it should return admin client id. Please suggest where I am missing something.
but count in  @countTotal is setting.

```
      **select @countTotal := COUNT(*) from Client WHERE vc_client_key = vc_client_key;

    SELECT @in_client_id := in_client_id from Client WHERE vc_client_key = 'admin';
    select @in_client_id;**
```

Comment: can u provide full code?

Comment: Thanks I solved it. I was using in_client_id  as local variable name , this name also belongs to table column name. when changes name inside local var it seems working.. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I solved it. I was using in_client_id as local variable name , this name also belongs to table column name. when changes name inside local var it seems working.. thanks...